# Best practice to autowire Spring-Bean with extended generics

Tags: java, spring, generics, inheritance, autowired

I'm setting up a generic Service Structure in a Java Spring Backend. I have a Service with the following Signature

```
public class GenericService<T, S extends ObjectService<T>> { ... }
```

In this service I am autowiring S like that:

```
@Autowired
private S objectService;
```

I also have 3 Services implementing the ObjectService Interface:

- UserService implements ObjectService
- LocationService implements ObjectService
- CompanyService implements ObjectService

In another Service i would like to autowire the following concrete Services:

```
@Autowired
private GenericService<User, UserService> genericUserExportService;

@Autowired
private GenericService<Location, LocationService> genericLocationExportService;

@Autowired
private GenericService<Company, CompanyService> genericCompanyExportService;
```

Trying this i am the followin error message:

```
expected single matching bean but found 3
```

I already found a solution with creating a subclass from GenericService for User, Location and Company, but i don't like it because i need to generate lots of empty subclasses like for instance:

```
public class GenericUserService extends GenericService<User, UserService> { ... }
```

Is there a better solution for my problem?

Comment: This can be 'solved' using qualifiers.

Comment: You can `@Autowire` using the class name or you can add the `@Qualifier` annotation to provide the target class name.

Comment: Question: based on what condition in your request you switch between User or Location or Company?

Comment: How does qualifiers solve that problem? My Problem is, that spring can't autowire the objectService Bean of the generic type S and I am looking for a solution without creationg sublcasses for each case but if i got it right i need to create subclasses to work with qualifiers?

Comment: @Jayesh in that specific case i know in the calling function which Service (with type User, Location or Company) to call.